# Android cameraX analyzer ImageProxy dimensions

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax, mlvision

I am using the camera preview along with an face analyzer (mlkit face detection). I noticed that the dimensions of the `ImageProxy` returned from the `analyze` function are not the same as the resolution i ve set in the config. That is causing issues with the bounding box for the `FaceGraphic`. Is there something i am missing with setting the resolution in the analysis config?

Comment: The output dimension is on a best-effort basis, because the camera hardware may not support the dimension configured by the app. What is the specific issue are you are running into?

Comment: Did you manage to get it work?

Comment: @Balasubramanian unfortunately no. Let me know if you find any solution on this one

Comment: I can able to make the changes in ImageAnalysis and PreviewConfig. Both have an independent config to control the target resolution. Maybe you can try with this

Comment: @Balasubramanian I ve tried adjusting the different configs. Can you share you code to have a look how you've done it please?

Comment: what `res` are you expecting from imageProxy? bcz it has a limit of `1080`

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuv8uK-5CLY&t=774s